# Pandas Series[Unknown] error when using Pylance

Tags: python, pandas, pylance, pyright

Using VSCode with Pylance, creating a basic series with pandas shown here will show an error. I looked around online and this question hasn't been asked yet, so I'm assuming I have some basic setup done incorrectly.

Using conda, python@3.8.3, pandas@1.4.4

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd

test_series = pd.Series([1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

```py
(variable) test_series: Series[Unknown]
Type of "test_series" is partially unknown
  Type of "test_series" is "Series[Unknown]"PylancereportUnknownVariableType
```

Comment: The two lines of code you listed above works well

Comment: @gtomer it works well, but do you know how to edit the vscode settings, so that the squiggly line isn't there?

Comment: What are the vscode settings?

Answer (score 1):

It's an embarrassingly lame answer, but this will kill the warnings:

```
from typing import List
import pandas as pd

lst: List[int] = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
test_series: pd.Series[int] = pd.Series(lst)
```

[I came here looking for a similar answer, so you are not along struggling with Python types and Pandas.]